# How to return a Code of Sequence(String) as a dict, which tells me how often a Amino-Acid occured?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

Basically I'm trying to write a program, which runs through a string, and returns all possible Amino-Acids and how often they occuring. I made this program, which gives me the names but not the numbers. Can someone please help me?

```
DNA_Codons = {
# U
'UUU': 'Phenylalanin', 'UCU': 'Serin', 'UAU': 'Tyrosin', 'UGU': 'Cystein',  # UxU
'UUC': 'Phenylalanin', 'UCC': 'Serin', 'UAC': 'Tyrosin', 'UGC': 'Cystein',  # UxC
'UUA': 'Leucin', 'UCA': 'Serin', 'UAA': '---', 'UGA': '---',  # UxA
'UUG': 'Leucin', 'UCG': 'Serin', 'UAG': '---', 'UGG': 'Tryptophan',  # UxG

# C
'CUU': 'Leucin', 'CCU': 'Prolin', 'CAU': 'Histidin', 'CGU': 'Arginin',  # CxU
'CUC': 'Leucin', 'CCC': 'Prolin', 'CAC': 'Histidin', 'CGC': 'Arginin',  # CxC
'CUA': 'Leucin', 'CCA': 'Prolin', 'CAA': 'Glutamin', 'CGA': 'Arginin',  # CxA
'CUG': 'Leucin', 'CCG': 'Prolin', 'CAG': 'Glutamin', 'CGG': 'Arginin',  # CxG

# A
'AUU': 'Isoleucin', 'ACU': 'Threonin', 'AAU': 'Asparagin', 'AGU': 'Serin',  # AxU
'AUC': 'Isoleucin', 'ACC': 'Threonin', 'AAC': 'Asparagin', 'AGC': 'Serin',  # AxC
'AUA': 'Isoleucin', 'ACA': 'Threonin', 'AAA': 'Lysin', 'AGA': 'Arginin',  # AxA
'AUG': 'Met', 'ACG': 'Threonin', 'AAG': 'Lysin', 'AGG': 'Arginin',  # AxG

# G
'GUU': 'Valin', 'GCU': 'Alanin', 'GAU': 'Asparaginsäure', 'GGU': 'Glycin',  # GxU
'GUC': 'Valin', 'GCC': 'Alanin', 'GAC': 'Asparaginsäure', 'GGC': 'Glycin',  # GxC
'GUA': 'Valin', 'GCA': 'Alanin', 'GAA': 'Glutaminsäure', 'GGA': 'Glycin',  # GxA
'GUG': 'Valin', 'GCG': 'Alanin', 'GAG': 'Glutaminsäure', 'GGG': 'Glycin'  # GxG }

def translate_code(seq, init_pos=0):
return {
    DNA_Codons[seq[pos:pos + 3]]
    for pos in range(init_pos, len(seq) - 2, 3)
} 

print(translate_code("ACAAUUGACACAUAUCGUCGAGGGUGGCCA"))
```

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
{'Threonin': 2, 'Isoleucin': 1, 'Asparaginsäure': 1, 'Tyrosin': 1, 'Arginin': 2, 
'Glycin': 1, 'Tryptophan': 1, 'Prolin': 1}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with bioinformatics but, for my enlightenment, isn't this RNA rather than DNA?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np    



def count_amino_acids(seq, init_pos=0):

    #First, create an amino acid dictionary from the codon dictionary:
    count_dict = {}    
    
    # go from the initial position, to full length in steps of 3
    for i in np.arange(init_pos, len(seq), 3): 
        codon = seq[i:i+3] # get the codon
        aa = DNA_Codons[codon] # look up the amino acid
        
        if aa == '---':       # stop at stop codons
            return count_dict
        
        count_dict[aa] += 1 # increment the counter

    return count_dict
    
count_amino_acids("ACAAUUGACACAUAUCGUCGAGGGUGGCCA")
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! This code works, but I forgot one thing to tell you guys: The output should not return Acids, which aren't part of the string. So the output should look like this: {'Leucin': 1, 'Arginin': 2, 'Alanin': 2, 'Tyrosin': 1, 'Serin': 1, 'Isoleucin': 2, 'Phenylalanin': 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
def translate_code(seq, init_pos=0):
    final_codons = {}
    for pos in range(init_pos, len(seq) - 2, 3):
        current_codon = DNA_Codons[seq[pos:pos + 3]]
        if current_codon in final_codons:
            final_codons[current_codon] += 1
        else:
            final_codons[current_codon] = 1
    return final_codons
```

This should work exactly as you specified for it to.

Comment: Thanks, this code works too! I forgot one thing to tell you guys: The output should not return Acids, which aren't part of the string. So the output should look like this: {'Leucin': 1, 'Arginin': 2, 'Alanin': 2, 'Tyrosin': 1, 'Serin': 1, 'Isoleucin': 2, 'Phenylalanin': 1}.

Comment: That's what it does. It only returns the acids that are part of the string. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Counter class from the collections module:

To exclude the combinations you don't want I would suggest not placing them in the codon dictionary at all.  I also inverted your dictionary to reduce the number of repetitions and make it more maintainable.

Setup:

```
acids = { 'Alanin':        ['GCA', 'GCC', 'GCG', 'GCU'],
          'Arginin':       ['AGA', 'AGG', 'CGA', 'CGC', 'CGG', 'CGU'],
          'Asparagin':     ['AAC', 'AAU'],
          'Asparaginsäure':['GAC', 'GAU'],
          'Cystein':       ['UGC', 'UGU'],
          'Glutamin':      ['CAA', 'CAG'],
          'Glutaminsäure': ['GAA', 'GAG'],
          'Glycin':        ['GGA', 'GGC', 'GGG', 'GGU'],
          'Histidin':      ['CAC', 'CAU'],
          'Isoleucin':     ['AUA', 'AUC', 'AUU'],
          'Leucin':        ['CUA', 'CUC', 'CUG', 'CUU', 'UUA', 'UUG'],
          'Lysin':         ['AAA', 'AAG'],
          'Met':           ['AUG'],
          'Phenylalanin':  ['UUC', 'UUU'],
          'Prolin':        ['CCA', 'CCC', 'CCG', 'CCU'],
          'Serin':         ['AGC', 'AGU', 'UCA', 'UCC', 'UCG', 'UCU'],
          'Threonin':      ['ACA', 'ACC', 'ACG', 'ACU'],
          'Tryptophan':    ['UGG'],
          'Tyrosin':       ['UAC', 'UAU'],
          'Valin':         ['GUA', 'GUC', 'GUG', 'GUU'] }
codons = { seq:name for name,sequences in acids.items() for seq in sequences }
```

Counting:

```
from collections import Counter
def translate_code(seq, init_pos=0):
    return Counter( codons[seq[pos:pos + 3]]
                    for pos in range(init_pos, len(seq), 3)
                    if seq[pos:pos + 3] in codons)
```

output:

```
print(translate_code("ACAAUUGACACAUAUCGUCGAGGGUGGCCA"))

Counter({'Threonin': 2, 'Arginin': 2, 'Isoleucin': 1, 'Asparaginsäure': 1, 'Tyrosin': 1, 'Glycin': 1, 'Tryptophan': 1, 'Prolin': 1})
```

*Note, the Counter class is actually a dictionary.  You can cast it back to a normal dictionary if needed.*

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. I made some changes to your code. Note: mine is not inside a function.

````
d = {}
s = "ACAAUUGACACAUAUCGUCGAGGGUGGCCA"
for i in range(0, len(s) - 2, 3):
    d[DNA_Codons[s[i:i+3]]] = s.count(s[i:i+3])
print(di) ```
````